# What is the difference between \$g_m\$ and \$g_{FS}\$?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

I am designing a 2N7000 mosfet common source amplifier with \$A_{mid}=5\$ requirement. To design this circuit I looked up 2N7000's datasheet ([here](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NDS7002A-D.PDF)) and here it is written \$g_{FS}=320 mS\$. And I am using this formula to calculate gain \$A_{mid}=-g_m(R_L||R_d)(1+\frac{R_f}{R_2})\$ May I use \$g_{FS}\$ value instead of \$g_m\$

Comment: This is completely a guess, but perhaps it's "forward, common-source" similar to how \$h_{FE}\$ is "forward, common-emitter"?

Comment: GFS is the transconductance for a MOSFET. Gm is a generalized term not specific to a MOSFET

Comment: So in this condition is it valid to use the specific value for \$g_m\$?

Comment: *So in this condition is it valid to use the specific value for \$g_m\$* It looks like that is the case, so \$g_{fs} = g_m\$. But have a look at the values that the datasheet specifies: 80 mS (min), 320 mS (typ) that's a **factor 4** and the maximum isn't even specified. In a common source circuit (without a source resistor) the gain \$A\$ is directly proportional to \$g_m\$ so \$A\$ is also going to vary a lot. If you don't want that, use **source degeneration** by adding a source resistor.

Comment: I would only use a 2N7000 as a switch or as a source follower, using it in a common source circuit will give poor performance. The 2N7000 and most other discrete MOSFETs are designed to be used as **switches**, not (linear) amplifiers.